# Transform: translate(0,0); not working on IONIC in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I create HTML File for test like this

```
<html><head>
<style>
.wrapper{
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
.container{
    height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.container1{
    background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/900/600);
}
.container2{
    background-color: white;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container container1">
        </div>
        <div class="container container2">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I test this code on Google Chrome & Firefox. It work correctly of both browser. (For fixed Position of image) But I apply above code to ionic like this...

```
<style>
.wrapper{
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
.container{
    height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.container1{
    background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/900/600);
}
.container2{
    background-color: white;
}
</style>

<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container container1">
            </div>
            <div class="container container2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The second code work correctly in Firefox but not in Google Chrome (Image not fixed position like first code). Thank for any help.

Comment: What version of Chrome did you try this on? Some early versions of Chrome require `-webkit` prefix .. `webkit-transform`  .. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: I use Chrome version 46.0.2490.80 @JonathanMarzullo